# Casting allocated memory through double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I don't understand clearly what happens when you cast allocated memory through  double pointer, as:

```
char **ptr;
ptr=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*value); 
for(i=0;i<value;i++)
   ptr[i]=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*another_value);
```

During the first call of malloc, a void * is casted to char * so, i can access it using *(ptr+i), but during the second call of malloc i don't understand why i need to cast void * to char **, would not be enough to cast it to char * ?

Comment: The cast from `void *` to any pointer type is automatic, your code is wrong, turn on compiler warnings and see.

Comment: You have it backwards.  You should be creating an array of `char *` in the outer loop and an array of `char` in the inner loop.

Comment: I suggest avoiding the phrase "double pointer"; use " pointer to pointer" unless you're referring to the type `double*`.

Comment: the code should always check the returned value from an call to the malloc family of functions to assure the operation was successful

Comment: for several reasons, the returned value from malloc (and family) should not be cast.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It is a good idea to cast the void pointer returned by malloc to the type of the destination pointer. In this case you can find an error similar to the error in your code snippet.

```
char **ptr;
ptr=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*value);
```

Here variable `ptr` has type `char **` while the right side of the assignment statement has type `char *` due to the casting. So the compiler shall issue an error (more precisely a diagnostic message) because there is no implicit conversion from `char *`. to `char **`

By the way by this reason in C++ there is not allowed to assign a pointer of type `void *` to pointers of other types because such a code is unsafe.

The other reason to cast the void pointer returned by malloc is to make your code self-documented. Consider for example the following statement

```
p = malloc( sizeof( *p ) );
```

Here it is difficult to understand what is the type of memory is allocated. It would be much better to write for example

```
p = ( double * )malloc( sizeof( *p ) );
```

In this case the statement is more clear and you need not to scroll a big program listing that to determine what is the type of p.

Take into account that a good program is a program where each statement provides you as much information as you need that to understand what the statement is trying to do and what types of variables envolved in expressions..

There is one  more reason to cast the pointer returned by malloc. If you will try to compile your code with a C++ compiler then it will issue numerous errors for each using of malloc without casting. When you will transfer your code from C to C++ you will estimate the value of such casting.

Here is the correct using of malloc for your example

```
char **ptr;

ptr = ( char ** )malloc( value * sizeof( char * ) ); 
for ( i = 0; i < value; i++ )
   ptr[i] = ( char * )malloc( another_value * sizeof( char ) );
```

Comment: There is no need to be offensive, if I didn't comment you it would be ok to be angry. But I commented since this has been very much discussed everywhere and the resulting conclusion is that it's [not a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) to cast from `void *`, it's not wrong either.

Comment: If you are such a high qualified programmer why did you write this "_o the compiler shall issue an error because there is no implicit conversion from char *_"? did you try to compile that? Are you sure it's an error? it's just a warning.

Comment: @iharob  No, I did not try. There is no any need to try to compile the code. Take into account that compilers have bugs or their own "extensions" that contradict the C Standard. In any case the compiler shall issue a diagnostic message. But in any case it is in essence an error.

Comment: You are right with the last part. But you are very wrong with the rest, because it's not necessary to offend any one and your are expressing your opinion so you can say _`I think it's a good Idea to cast ...`_, I actually think that SO should warn the moderators when someone uses words like _`idiot`_... It's not necessary at all.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow; Didn't downvoted but for your information: **C11-7.22.3.4:** `The malloc function returns either a null pointer or a pointer to the allocated space.` You can also see their that there is no casting before `malloc` in the entire document.

Comment: @haccks  And what? Most of code examples in the C Standard are examples how code shall not be written. The task of the code examples in the C Standard is not to show how the code shall be written in projects. Their task is to show peculiarities of the language.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow; *The task of code examples in the C Standard is not to show how the code shall be written in projects.*: Disagree.

Comment: @haccks  I advice you to read my answer one more and think about it. It will be more helpful for you then reading of references you gave.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow; I didn't read you question at first. But after marked as accepted, the 3 downvotes tempted me to read the answer. I read your complete answer and I concluded that you may seem to be relating with the return value of `malloc` in C++ with C. In C++, return value of `malloc` must be casted.

Comment: @haccks First of all C++ improved some weak points of C. But the main reason is not that I follow C++ . The main reason is to write good safe and clear code.

Comment: @haccks  If you may use some language constructions it does not mean that you should use them.

Answer (score 5):

Casting in the above snippet makes no sense. [Do not cast return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2455888).  And allocation is wrong too. It should be like:

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(char*)*value);
```

and

```
ptr[i] = malloc(another_value);
```

Comment: I think you want to add `* value` to the first `malloc()` (to be consistent with what's in the question); also, worth pointing out that `sizeof(char)` is redundant since the size is returned in `char`s...

Comment: @psmears; You are right. No need of `sizeof(char)` here.

Comment: Just to be 100% clear, the downvoter wasn't me (I upvoted after your edit!). I'd also be interested to know the reasons for the downvote...

Answer (score 3):

Both are wrong.

Both casts are unnecessary as a void pointer (`malloc` returns `void*`) is compatible with any other data pointer.

See: http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

First of all no need to cast `malloc()` Please take a look at the changes below.

Since the return type of `malloc()` is `void *` no need to cast `malloc()`

```
char **ptr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*another_value);

for(i=0;i<value;i++)
ptr[i]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*value);
```

Remove cast and have

```
char **ptr = malloc(sizeof(char *)*another_value);

for(i=0;i<value;i++)
ptr[i]= malloc(sizeof(char)*value);
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but you should be using `sizeof(char*)*value` instead of `sizeof(char*)*another_value`.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is

```
char **ptr;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * value); // value pointers of char
for(i=0;i<value;i++)
    ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*another_value); // another_value of chars
```

your code compiled because `void *` is automatically converted to any pointer type, but if you turn on warnings, the compiler would notify you that you are assigning pointers of incompatible types.

Without the casts however no warning will be issued.

Another thing, `sizeof(char) != sizeof(char *)` you need `value` pointers to `char` and then each pointer will be pointing to `another_value` array of `char`s.

So the first call to `malloc` you have to allocate `value * sizeof(pointer)`, the syntax for that is

```
value * sizeof(char *)
/*                  ^ see the star here. */
```

and then you don't need `sizeof(char)` since it's `1`, the following is correct

```
char **ptr;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * value); // value pointers of char
for(i=0;i<value;i++)
    ptr[i] = malloc(another_value); // another_value of chars
```